# Workbook Variable overwritten without call

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently Looping through a sheet in excel and linking Key values with another worksheet before entering data from both into my current workbook.
However when opening the 3rd Workbook in VB the variable containing the 2nd Workbook is being overwritten to also contain the 3rd workbook.

```
Set CheckWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("Checkworkbook.xlsx")

For Each File In Folder.Files
Set DataWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(File)
For i = 2 To NumRows
CurrentTransaction = DataWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value
    For j = 2 To CheckNumRows
        CheckTransaction = CheckWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value ' Reads Data from DataWorkbook instead of CheckWorkbook
        If CurrentTransaction = CheckTransaction Then
        'Process Data
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Next
```

Anyone seen something similar? Or is excel only capable of worming with two workbooks? 
Running in Excel 2016

Comment: Is Checkworkbook.xlsx one of the files in Folder.Files? Typically a name check is used to step over a situation like that.

Comment: Sorry, i should've clarified, They're in separate folders on separate drives. Folder.files in on a network drive (and works fine in other projects)

Comment: I have a routine that works with >20 workbooks.  Put a breakpoint on your `For i = ...` line and see exactly what DataWorkbook is pointing to during each iteration. Then check the `Folder` collection to ensure you are pointing to the correct folder.

Comment: Folder selection is correct and points to the first file of 31 and iterates through them (daily data dump for the month), however Checkworkbook is also being assigned to the daily file without any call for it while it should remain as Checkworkbook.xlsx

Comment: I don't get it. You open one workbook (`Checkworkbook`) and store it in one variable and you loop over a folder, in every iteration opening a file and assigning it to `DataWorkbook`. What is overwritten?

Comment: Checkworkbook is being overwritten to point to the same file as Dataworkbook, i don't quite get it either

Comment: Is it overwritten and the `open`-statement inside the loop or later while processing? Have you debugged your code and checked?

Comment: On what line, exactly, does it get overwritten?  Go step-by-step to debug and see where it changes.

Comment: Checkworkbook is overwritten on the same line that dataworkbook is opened.

Comment: Is the code in a **Regular** Module?

Comment: Yep, regular bog standard Module1

Comment: So if, in the `Immediate Window`, you type `?Checkworkbook.name`, before and after that statement executes, it actually returns a different name?

Comment: And there's no other code between `Set Checkworkbook` and `For Each File` lines?

Answer (score 0):

Moved the code into one of the data files as a workaround, Not a true answer but its one way to do it.

Will continue testing once finished to find the source of the original problem and update